# Remove access on report for a user in classic only

Tags: lightning, custom-reports, salesforce-classic

I want to remove user to access reports form classic. But the same user should access reports from lightning. Do any one have any idea how to handle this?

Comment: What is the use case you are trying to achieve? Any specific reason to block report access to users on Classic?

Comment: @Swetha, our customer is was using classic now they switch to lightning. Now even after using lightning the user is able to create reports in classic. They only wan to create reports from lightning only.

Comment: *Why* do they want to do this, though? As written, this may be an [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/), so without more information on the underlying situation, there's really not much we can do to answer this right now.

Comment: would it not suffice to remove the ability for them to switch to Classic? +1 to what @sfdcfox said

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to remove classic access to the Reports. If you remove system permissions to access reports and dashboards in classic, users won’t be able to access reports and dashboards in LEX too. As suggested in the comments, the only alternative would be to [remove the "switch to Classic](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.lex_enable_users_disable_switcher.htm&type=5)" experience.

Recommend you to checkout [LEX adoption strategies](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/lex_migration_rollout/lex_migration_rollout_enabling)

You can remove the Embedded classic report builder by [Hiding the embedded Salesforce Classic report builder in Lightning Experience](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.customize_reports_and_dashboards_lightning_report_builder.htm&type=5) to have better adoption to LEX Reports. With this, users no longer see the New Report (Salesforce Classic) and Edit (Salesforce Classic) buttons on the Reports tab in Lightning Experience.